# In Python IDLE 2.7, why is raw_input storing multiple values?

Tags: python, variables, python-idle, local-variables, raw-input

I'm trying to build a hangman game in Python, and I've set it repeat the input function if the user inputs a letter they've already tried. For some reason though, the "guess" variable stores every single value that I try, and I'm confused why this is happening. I only want it to store the most recent input. Here's the code:

```
def inputGuess(lettersGuessed):

    guess = raw_input("What is your guess? ")
    guess = guess.lower()
    if guess in lettersGuessed:
        print "You've already guessed that. Try again!"
        inputGuess(lettersGuessed)
    print guess
    return guess
```

And the output (as a note, the first 'a' was pre-loaded to test the 'if' statement):

```
>>> 
Loading word list from file...
55900 words loaded.
The secret word has 8 letters!
Available letters: bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
What is your guess? a
You've already guessed that. Try again!
What is your guess? a
You've already guessed that. Try again!
What is your guess? a
You've already guessed that. Try again!
What is your guess? f
f
a
a
a
['a', 'a']
>>>
```

The print statement shows that multiple values seem to be involved. Can anyone explain why this is happening? I feel like I must be missing something obvious. Thanks so much!

Comment: You call `inputGuess` from within `inputGuess`. Maybe you should use a `while True:` / `if condition: break` loop instead.

Comment: Your code never adds anything to `lettersGuessed`, so I don't see how it ever gets *anything* in there.  Also, you don't show how you're calling `inputGuess` in the first place.  Are you pasting the actual code you are running?

Comment: Doing the 6.00SC MIT course? :) I believe that's from the first problem set, right?

Comment: Indeed it is 6.00SC. I started late so I'm still playing catch-up. And the other variables I call are part of other methods. I simply posted what I thought was relevant as opposed to all the code. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling yourself recursively like that is a bad idea. Eventually you'll get an exception. The proper way to handle this is a `while` loop

```
def inputGuess(lettersGuessed):
    while True:
        guess = raw_input("What is your guess? ")
        guess = guess.lower()
        if guess in lettersGuessed:
            print "You've already guessed that. Try again!"
        else:
            break
    print guess
    return guess
```

Comment: The problem would be even more apparent if the OP called up the stack viewer in IDLE (with `assert False` somewhere in his r. loop).

Comment: Perfect! That fixed the problem. I'm still a tad confused why it printed out multiple values, but the dangers of recursive calling make some sense. Thanks so much!

Comment: @user2141768, It will save all the duplicates on the stack for each recursive call. You'll see them all printed once you enter a new guess that bypasses the `if`

Comment: Ahhh that makes perfect sense. Definitely something good to keep in mind!